# Asking for email introduction of the new coworker to the whole group

Tags: professionalism, colleagues, email, team, new-hires

We have a new temporary coworker in our lab (it is academia, but not academia-specific question). There are about 12 people working here.

I would like to ask for a lab-wide introduction of this student, with their name and role. I feel that email to the whole group would be very useful for everyone, something like:

> Hi y'all, we have a new temp. Her name is Alice Joe and she will be helping Mark Jane with pipetting for the next N months.

**What is the professional way to ask somebody else in the group to send this intro email?** I think it's not part of the culture, but I have worked here for 3 months and people are very friendly.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You could even introduce the temp in person. It doesn't really matter either way. Either of those options is professional.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk i think email is better because - personally - my memory for names lasts like 5 seconds

Comment: You could do both

Comment: @aaaaasaysreinstateMonica Are you asking how to send the email yourself — as the lone answer assumes — or how to get someone else to do it (presumably someone who knows who the new person is?)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill your second assumption is correct, i will edit it into the Q

Comment: 1) do it in person - always (Ick! Shudder! The very idea of not doing so, and just sending an email !!) 2) `Mark Jane` - seriously, you work with someone named `Mark Jane` ? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the professional way to do it?

I think it's fine to send an email to the team as you mentioned (personally, I would use more formal phrasing, and avoid using things like "y'all").

Alternatively, if possible, when everybody is gathered in the lab you could introduce the new member in person to the team as whole (or to the ones present), in case you feel an in-person introduction would be better.

But if not, an email should suffice.

Comment: Agree about the "y'all" - it may be the new and inclusive "guys", but I'd never start a workplace email with either - say "Hi all" or "Hi everyone"

Answer (score 2):

You can simply ask whoever you think is most likely to know about the new person:

> Ms. A, I noticed we have a new person working in the lab, but they haven’t been introduced around. Could you do it? Or maybe you could send out an email letting everyone know who they are, who they’re working with, etc.

Now, all that said: most academic labs and workplaces have periodic “group meetings” where this sort of thing is handled. If your lab doesn’t do this, perhaps you should suggest that it’s time to start them!

Comment: we do have lab meeting, next one is in like 2 weeks :)